# slick-slider with Corresponding Image Section

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I've made a simple slider using Ken Wheeler's slick-slider (https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), and I've added an image display function that switches another image below the slider (not the actual slider image) to correspond with the slider. I'd like this for a product carousel that will have a banner image that corresponds with the product in the slick-slider. The below code is functional, but was wondering if there's a cleaner way achieve this. I got hung-up and perhaps long-winded when checking for the inactive slides, and hiding the corresponding images. Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.my-slide-wrapper').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 1,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    });
    $("button.slick-arrow").click(function () {
        if ($("#slick-slide00").hasClass("slick-active") && (!$("#slick-slide01 #slick-slide02").hasClass("slick-active"))) {
            $("#myImage00").addClass("im-showing"),
                $("#myImage01").removeClass("im-showing"),
                $("#myImage02").removeClass("im-showing");
        }
        else if ($("#slick-slide01").hasClass("slick-active") && (!$("#slick-slide02 #slick-slide00").hasClass("slick-active"))) {
            $("#myImage01").addClass("im-showing"),
                $("#myImage02").removeClass("im-showing"),
                $("#myImage00").removeClass("im-showing");
        }
        else {
            $("#myImage02").addClass("im-showing"),
                $("#myImage01").removeClass("im-showing"),
                $("#myImage00").removeClass("im-showing");
        }
    });
});
```

Working version on CodePen: https://codepen.io/jakeos/pen/povXPyd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out "Slider Syncing" in the documentation. It does exactly that. In your case, you need to setup both as sliders and use your top slider as the navigation for the bottom one.

*I changed your HTML a bit to make it easier to understand*

[Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6k4c2bd7/1/).

```
HTML

<!-- This is just a slider using Ken Wheeler's slick-slider (https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), and I've added an image display function that switches the image below (the slider) to correspond with the slider. It will ultimately be for a product carousel that will have a banner image that corresponds with the product in the slider. -->

<body>

    <div class="my-slide-container">

        <div id="top-slider" class="my-slide-wrapper">
            <img class="slide slide00" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x180/ff0000/ffffff.jpg&text=Slide+1">
            <img class="slide slide01" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x180/00ff00/000000.jpg&text=Slide+2">
            <img class="slide slide02" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x180/0000ff/ffffff.jpg&text=Slide+3">
        </div>

        <div id="bottom-slider" class="my-slide-wrapper">
            <img class="slide slide00" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x180/ff0000/ffffff.jpg&text=Image+1">
            <img class="slide slide01" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x180/00ff00/000000.jpg&text=Image+2">
            <img class="slide slide02" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x180/0000ff/ffffff.jpg&text=Image+3">
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

CSS

```
.my-slide-container {
  margin: 30px;
}

.my-slide-wrapper,
.my-image-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 300px;
}

img {
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.slick-dots li {
  margin: 0;
}

.slick-next::before,
.slick-prev::before {
  color: #000;
  opacity: 1;
}

.my-image {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

#myImage00 {
  visibility: visible;
}

.im-hiding {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.im-showing {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#top-slider').slick({
        asNavFor: '#bottom-slider',
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 1,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    });

    $('#bottom-slider').slick({
        arrows: false,
        dots: false,
        draggable: false,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 1,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    });

});
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you, @vvv. Great call. I've updated here: https://codepen.io/jakeos/pen/zYxVjbW